# discordpy suggestion command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

My code:

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, suggestion):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = "New suggestion.",
        description = f"{suggestion}",
        color = 0,
        timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
    )
    embed.set_footer(text='Requested by {} | ID-{}' .format(ctx.message.author, ctx.message.author.id))

    await ctx.guild.owner.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.send("Suggestion sent to server owner.")
```

Problem with this command is that bot does not read the whole message, it reads only first word of it.
For example I send this message: `=suggest this is suggestion` And bot sends embed to a owner only with the first word in this case it will send embed with only `this` and not whole sentence. If it is possible, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the keyword-only argument

```py
async def suggest(ctx, *, suggestion):
```

Take a look at the [introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)